# How to remove background that is visible through the windows using Opencv or DeepLearning?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

1. I was able to remove the background from the cars using deep learning but I am unable to segment BG that is visible through the windows of the car.
2. Is there any way of smoothing the edges of the car other than blurring them?

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJBAi.jpg)

[Segmented Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZEQW.png)

[Generated Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryvul.jpg)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljcvI.png)

Comment: have you looked at [double dip](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/DoubleDIP/index.html)? it handles segmentation and transparency.

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll try.

Comment: You could try to segment the image using a Grabcut variant initialized with the network output, it should regularize the edges, you could also use a Conditional Random Field (CRF) on the output layer of the network, put this would decrease greatly the network processing speed.

Comment: I have tried grab-cut on network output, it made edges even more jagged than before. I'll look into CRF. Thanks.

Comment: I have used CRF on network output, more background in being classified as foreground. CRFs didn't improve the model performance.